# MySQL rearange auto increment after row is deleted

Tags: php, mysql

I was searching for a solution to my problem and didn't find one. Basically the user can add/delete information which will delete the row. The user can also arrange this information up/down which would also switch the primary keys (called placeholder). The problems are is that if the user deletes a row it won't move the placeholder int up one. I was wondering If there's any way to move the rows up and arrange them starting from 1.

Comment: I think something like `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl);` should do it but you shouldn't mess with your PK.

Comment: I didn't think you could change the aug increment of a table?

Comment: You should create a separate column to track orders rather than manipulating primary key.

Comment: Manipulation of the Auto increment field is a path less traveled. As @fallenAngel said, you should have your own incrementing field handled with the insert statements within your PHP code. Leave your set one as it is, after all.. They are Unique for a reason

Comment: now the problem I face if its a seperate column. Thanks now I have to figure out if i should use auto increment for that new non-primary column or If I should manage the order though php. thanks

Comment: @AndreYonadam : It's dead simple.  Blatantly ignore the autoincrementing column, trying to use that to organise and retreieve files is more work than need be.

Set your primary key to be an int, unique and then use that to pull all queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't amend auto increment.  It's part of the database design. You should use another column name as the identifier, ID perhaps?

Comment: You can reset/amend the auto increment after a truncating a table. This is not an answer rather a comment.

Comment: I often ignore the use of an auto incrementing field for this reason. I just manage an int primary key of my own as this answer suggests.

Comment: exactly.  the auto inc is just there to be ignored.  By me anyway.  ID as primary key is always the best way to go, in my humble opinion that is.